# YouTubeStandAlonePlayer in Fullscreen mode with both Portrait and Landscape without restarting (Android)

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Im using a YouTubeStandAlonePlayer to play a youtube video in my app
When I use YouTubeStandAlonePlayer in LightBox Mode the video rotates whenever the device orientation changes and does not restart the activity
However when I use YouTubeStandAlonePlayer in fullscreen mode it only plays in landscape mode

My app only operates in portrait mode, but when I play a video via. YouTubeStandAlonePlayer I want it to enter full screen and be able to change to both portrait and landscape mode as the orientation changes. When the user exits the video I want the app to go back to portrait mode regardless of what orientation the full screen video was being played in.

I've seen this functionality in Flipboard when YouTube Videos are played

I've been stumbling around this for weeks can someone please help me!!

Comment: no solution so far?

Comment: I want to get solution too. Could anybody fix this?